# How do I integrate the signup/ signin using LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, authentication, linkedin-api

How do I integrate the signup/ signin using LinkedIn profile rather than your app registration/login? A step by step guidance will be helpful for me. (Using Javascript and REST Api calls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do that exactly: http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/using-linkedin-javascript-api-for-user-authentication-and-profile-retrieval.html

Please use search engines like Google in the future, and only ask for help here when you are running into a problem that you can't find elsewhere.